# SSH doesn't work on Ubuntu !

Tags: ssh, iptables, remote-access

I am trying to connect to my webserver via ssh but I can't. When I insert the password then the terminal is blocked. This is what I see:

```
# ssh username@username.example.com
username@username.example.com's password:
```

Why ?
In iptables there are no rules.
Please help :(

Comment: What do you mean, "blocked"? Nothing happens afterwards?

Comment: isn't the right syntax, username@example.com?

Comment: this is not a programming related question, try superuser.com

Comment: What do the logs say in /var/log? There should be SSH or SSHD logfiles that may give some clue. If it's a DNS issue, the connection may be timing out; are you using a Mac to connect? I've had issues with that before where DNS reverse lookups time it out. Also, you can run SSH with a debugging verbose switch to see what the conversation is between client and server; run that and post the results to help with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are irritated that nothing after the password prompt is printed: that's perfectly normal. The characters of the password will not be printed. Just enter the (correct) password and press `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

`^C` character in your password can block the terminal if you are using PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the user account you're trying to log in with is in fact allowed to log in via SSH.